# Проблема с web audio API в google chrome

Tags: веб-программирование, api, google-chrome, аудио

Есть код, прекрасно работающий в Firefox, но почему-то не работающий в хроме (нет звука). В чем может быть проблема?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var audio = new Audio('audio');
  audio.toggle();

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    //Space
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
      audio.toggle();
    }
  });
});

function Audio(id) {
  var that = this;
  this.elem = document.getElementById(id);
  this.playing = false;

  var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
  var ctx = new AudioContext;
  var source = ctx.createMediaElementSource(this.elem);
  var dest = ctx.destination;
  var gain = ctx.createGain();


  source.connect(gain);
  gain.connect(dest);


  this.toggle = function() {
    if (that.playing) {
      that.elem.pause();
    } else {
      that.elem.play();
    }
    that.playing = !that.playing;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css' />
  <title>Web audio API</title>
</head>

<body>
  <audio src="someSong.mp3" id="audio"></audio>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: В консоли Chrome ошибок нет?

Comment: нет, совершенно ничего.

Answer (score 1):

Для Хрома, Яндекса и Оперы нужно защищенное соединение (https://) иначе он не дает доступ к микрофону